# Getting same response from a condition used in Redux firebase saga

Tags: firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I am trying to implement a condition in which I am using Firebase as a database. Condition work if a username already exists. but currently, it is working in both scenarios. like if the username doesn't exist it is still work

Here is my code block in the saga

```
  const snapshot = yield call(rsf.firestore.getDocument,`usernames/${values.username}`);
    if(snapshot.data) {
      yield put(stopSubmit(form, {username: "Username already exists"}));
      return
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer it's just a difference of "data" and "exists" 
the code block for answer :

```
const snapshot = yield call(rsf.firestore.getDocument,`usernames/${values.username}`);
    if(snapshot.exists) {
     yield put(stopSubmit(form, {username: "Username already exists"}));
     return;
   }
```